# Angular 2, add query param to route url

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I'm trying to add param for every route url in angular 2. In angular 1 that was easy you just need to specify some http interceptor, where you can define config param and angular automatically will add it to request and route url

```
'request': function(config) {
      config.params = config.params || {};
      config.params.myParam: paramId;
      return config;
    },

request api/endPoint?myParam=paramId
url domain/route?myParam=paramId
```

I was looking for something like in angular 2 but I've got only this:

```
createAuthRequest() {

    ...

    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('myParam', paramId);

    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.search = params;
    requestOptions.headers = head;
    return requestOptions
  }
```

request:

```
getData(): Promise<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.appServices.api + "/endPoint", this.appServices.createAuthRequest())
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => this.appServices.extractToken(response))
      .catch((err)=>{this.appServices.handleError(err);})
  }
```

in this case my request looks right:

```
api/endPoint?myParam=paramId
```

but my url doesn't:

```
domain/route
```

What am I missing and where is my mistake? How could I achieve this:

```
domain/route?myParam=paramId
```

Comment: This is a pain. I wrote an interceptor enabled client for my apps. There are some out there on npm/GitHub. The problem is that it sucks for integrating with other libraries. I ended up replacing `Http` instead of wrapping it, but this is dangerous as well.

Comment: @AluanHaddad and how can I beat it? I know that absolutely every route has to have the same param such as every request, which user gets after he has been logged in to the system, I just need to pass it to the route...

Comment: Personally, I would leverage some abstraction, such as an Http client offering interceptors, or write my own. This sort of duplication is unacceptable. The angular team deliberately removed interceptors and refused to reintroduce them. Sure they are not perfect, but they offer no equivalent. Many other use cases as well: setting request/response transformers, loading indicators, etc.

Comment: @AluanHaddad damn, this is headache..

Comment: If you want a bigger headache, enjoy reading this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2684 it also shows some ideas. If you want to ping me, I can send you some sample code.

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks for that, I appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143331/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-antonyboom).